# SGP4 TEME frame to J2000 conversion

Tags: frames, sgp4

I've got familiar with the SGP4 model. The problem which I faced is that, the results are in TEME frame.

How to convert the TEME to J2000?

Would be glad also, if you suggest a method in `python` or `julia`.

Comment: OK, I give up. What's the TEME frame? Googling didn't help.

Comment: @barrycarter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial#TEME

Comment: For the person posting a bounty.  I believe "Revisiting Spacetrack Report #3: Rev 3" is what you're looking for: https://celestrak.org/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/AIAA-2006-6753-Rev3.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is solved using the `Skyfield` and `Astropy` packages in python.

```
import skyfield.sgp4lib as sgp4lib
from astropy import coordinates as coord, units as u
from astropy.time import Time 

  # time- J2000 date
  # p,v- vectors, result of SGP4 in TEME frame
  date= datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0) + datetime.timedelta(days=time - 2451545)

  # Conversion from TEME to ITRS    
  p,v= sgp4lib.TEME_to_ITRF(time,np.asarray(p),np.asarray(v)*86400)
  v=v/86400

  # Conversion from ITRS to J2000    
  now = Time(date)
  itrs = coord.ITRS(p[0]*u.km, p[1]*u.km, p[2]*u.km, v[0]*u.km/u.s, v[1]*u.km/u.s, v[2]*u.km/u.s, obstime=now)
  gcrs = itrs.transform_to(coord.GCRS(obstime=now))
  p,v=gcrs.cartesian.xyz.value,gcrs.velocity.d_xyz.value
```

Comment: can you please explain the `days=time - 2451545` part? I don't really understand what's happening here. Is `time` the datetime at which you want to convert from TEME to J2000? Is it supposed to be expressed in days?

Comment: Hi the python code that is shown above using skyfield and astropy does not work because I guess it has been written in a previous version of python. Since I am totally greenhorn on python I need some help. How must this code be modified in order to be able to use it correctly with python 3.9.2. I posted the code again here bellow, because I tried already to get it run, and I think there where some bugs present in the original code (time must be Time and import datetime was missing) Thank you very much! PS: I am still not able to write comments, so I put my questions into answers, unfortunately

Comment: ...... Sacha Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/4e87Qj94

Comment: @Raksha 2451545 is the Julian date of noon UTC 1 Jan 2000. That is close to the J2000 epoch, which is noon TT 1 Jan 2000.

Comment: @SachaTholl The code as posted is worthless. I do not understand why this is the accepted and somewhat highly upvoted answer. The variable `time` is used but never never defined. The `imports` are wrong. This wouldn't have worked in python 2.7, let alone python 3.

Comment: Also @DavidHammen, they `skyfield` API says that the used method (`TEME_to_ITRF()`) is marked as deprecated:  `"""Deprecated: use the TEME and ITRS frame objects instead."""`

Answer (score 5):

I have published a julia package called [SatelliteToolbox.jl](https://github.com/SatelliteToolbox/SatelliteToolbox.jl) that has all the conversions related to IAU-76/FK5 model (ITRF, MOD, TOD, GCRF, PEF, etc.) and now I also added the support for TEME. However, you need to use the `master` branch because it is not released yet.

To install the package from `master`, you can do this:

```
Pkg.add("SatelliteToolbox")
Pkg.checkout("SatelliteToolbox")
```

If you have a vector represented in TEME `r_teme`, you can convert it to J2000 using:

```
D_J2000_TEME = rTEMEtoGCRF(JD_TT)
r_j2000 = D_J2000_TEME*r_teme
```

where `JD_TT` is the Julian Day in Terrestrial Time. If you only have the Julian Day in UTC, you can use `JD_TT = JD_UTCtoTT(JD_UTC)`.

This package also have a native implementation of SGP4 (**without SDP4 bits yet**). The computed vectors from the orbit propagator (position and velocity) are represented in TEME and can be converted to J2000 using the procedure above.

Notice that the definition of TEME in this package is the same as the one used by Vallado, since we do not have an "official" TEME definition. Moreover, all those transformations functions were heavily tested against the examples in the Vallado's book (as you can see in `./test/`) folder.

## UPDATE

With the newest commit, it is even easier:

```
using SatelliteToolbox

# Julian day at 2018-Feb-12 15:35:22 UTC
JD_UTC = DatetoJD(2018,2,12,15,35,22)

# DCM that rotates the TEME frame of Date `JD_UTC` into J2000.
D_J2000_TEME = rECItoECI(TEME(), J2000(), JD_UTC)

# Quaternion that rotates the TEME frame of Date `JD_UTC` into J2000.
q_J2000_TEME = rECItoECI(Quaternion, TEME(), J2000(), JD_UTC)
```

Comment: I do not think so, this was posted this year: asked 2 months ago

Comment: quite right @RonanArraesJardimChagas. American date format is confusing

Answer (score 3):

Tarlan is spot on with his answer but I wanted to tag along for those not using python or using some other software not being discussed here.

The general consensus is that converting directly between inertial frames gets messy and non-trivial. As a result it would be best to get TEME into a fixed/pseudo-fixed frame before converting it to your inertial frame of choice.

This works not only for J2000, but for any frame. TEME to ECF coordinate transforms are fairly common, especially with telecom companies who want to know what sort of coverage their satellites will be providing. From there going to ECF to whatever inertial frame you are working in will be trivial if you understand the relationship between your fixed and inertial coordinate systems.

Comment: A very late comment, but isn't the transformation from EC(E)F to another ECI frame non-trivial if factors like precession, nutation and polar motion are taken into account?

Comment: @jos only if you're trying to do things over time (in a way, generating ephemerides) - if you're just doing it for a single instant, it's easier.

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert the TEME to J2000? [using Python]

See: "[astropysics/astropysics/coords/coordsys.py](https://github.com/eteq/astropysics/blob/master/astropysics/coords/coordsys.py)", which is from the [Astrophysics](https://pythonhosted.org/Astropysics/) package.

See also:

"[Tracking satellite footprints on Earth’s surface](http://mycoordinates.org/tracking-satellite-footprints-on-earth%E2%80%99s-surface/)" or

"[Revisiting Spacetrack Report #3: Rev 2](https://celestrak.org/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/)", Appendix C - TEME Coordinate System.

[Source code](https://celestrak.org/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/AIAA-2006-6753.zip) (C++, FORTRAN, Java, MATLAB, Pascal. Total: 1,229,282 bytes, .ZIP File).

Comment: I can't find anything relating to the TEME frame there, do you have a line number? Or, if there isn't anything, maybe explain how one would use the different pieces here to accomplish the TEME <-> J2000 transformation?

Comment: @Chris As I know, astropy can convert from ITRS to J2000. For TEME->ITRS I used Skyfield. Added the code as answer.